# Fading effect in background

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I make my inline styled `div` to change it background image url after 5 second?

Example:

```
<div class="foobar" style=" background:(url'red.png')"> </div>
```

After 5 seconds, it need to be:

```
<div class="foobar" style=" background:(url'blue.png')"> </div>
```

and After 5 seconds, it need be:

```
<div class="foobar" style=" background:(url'yellow.png')"> </div>
```

So, It can cycle 3 images in this foobar, Red, Blue and Yellow background images.

Here is what I tried so far: **[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m61u51xt/1/)**

Comment: @DanielAlder It is example that what i tried with it and what problems it have.

Comment: @DanielAlder Fiddle do exactly the same stated in question. Cycling the image but not fading

Comment: Oh sorry, Now changed.

Comment: Now all set in question!

Comment: @DanielAlder Thank you!

Comment: _“It is example that what i tried with it and what problems it have”_ – _that_ code belongs _into_ your question (plus a description of the problems.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `setInterval()` instead :

```
setInterval(nextBackground, 5000);
```

If you want smooth fade in use the **[`fadeIn()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/)** function :

```
imagrep.hide().fadeIn();
```

**NOTE :** `fadeIn()` works only on hidden elements that why we have to hide the element first.

Hope this helps.

```js
$(function() {
  var imagrep = $('.foobar');
  var backgrounds = ['url(http://images.huffingtonpost.com/2016-03-02-1456944747-2376497-naturehike.jpg)', 'url(http://www.mindful.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/nature.jpg','url(http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/3d-nature-wallpaper1.jpg)'];
  var current = 0;

  function nextBackground() {
    imagrep.css('background',backgrounds[current]);
    imagrep.hide().fadeIn();
    
    if(current==backgrounds.length-1)
      current=0;
    else
      current++;
  }
  
  setInterval(nextBackground,2000);
});
```

```css
.foobar {
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="foobar" style="background:url(http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/3d-nature-wallpaper1.jpg);">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, It is still skipping the first image at start. It just quickly skip first image (Which entered in inline html) It should wait for first image

Comment: You're welcome, it's not skipping it please recheck the snippet.

Comment: Its not working in fiddle? (Plus see it do not wait for first image to load and it change it. https://jsfiddle.net/8b2kmhLa/

Comment: Works now https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/8b2kmhLa/2/ you have just missing to include the jquery lib.

Comment: Great! One last thing, Why it make page blank after last image. Not perfectly loop?

Comment: That not happen in the above fiddle it just loop perfectly :) ... (it may take time in some machines due to the loading of pictures from the source depending to connection speed, but the will be avoided using local pictures)..

Comment: See when using background color, It is not showing green again: https://jsfiddle.net/8b2kmhLa/3/

Comment: Totaly normal, it will not shown because the the code loop over the array of background if you want it to show you should add it there. https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/8b2kmhLa/4/ (If the answer is what you looking for mark it as **[Correct answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)**)

Answer (score 0):

You can't animate the background-image (or background with an image) property, but you can get a similar effect like this :

```
imagrep.animate({opacity: 0}, 'slow', function() {
    imagrep.css({'background-image': backgrounds[current = ++current % backgrounds.length]}).animate({opacity: 1});
});
```

This animate the opacity to 0, then change the image, and finally animate the opacity to 1.

Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m61u51xt/3/

Comment: Why it make page blank after last slide? not perfectly loop?

Comment: Weird... It makes a perfect loop to me

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use jquery Cycle plugin.
You can download it from

http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/

It's open source and easy to impliment and in addition you can add various effect like fadein, zoom and suffle etc.